Creating an ADO pipeline that triggers off another ADO pipeline isn't working
I have a pipeline named "ContainerWorker" that sits in a folder named "Atlas." I've created another pipeline in a branch that is just this:
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: container-worker
    source: '\Atlas\ContainerWorker'
    trigger: true

steps:
- bash: echo "This pipeline ran"

From these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops I'd expect this pipeline to run whenever ContainerWorker completes, but it's not doing that. I get no errors or anything useful to debug.
I've tried it without the quotes and without the folder with no luck.

With your yaml code, i can reproduce one time. Please check the details below:

Try to edit the pipeline resource trigger, for example: remove dash - for name container-worker, save the pipeline, this is in order to update the pipeline resource trigger. Then you can add dash in name back if you want.

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: containerworker             # <--- do some change to update the trigger
    source: '\Atlas\ContainerWorker'
    trigger: true

In addition, please edit the triggered pipeline yaml -> click vertical 3 dots on the top right -> Triggers -> YAML tab, Get Sources section -> make sure Default branch for manual and scheduled builds is correct, please check the doc for the details.


The pipeline resource trigger works:



If pipelines are in different project, please add project in the resource trigger:

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: container-worker
    project: sourceproject             #<----------- add project of source pipeline
    source: '\Atlas\ContainerWorker'
    trigger: true

In addition, you can firstly manually run both pipelines, make sure they are fine, and try the pipeline resource trigger again.

Changing the default branch worked! I was developing in a branch and didn't realize I'd need to change that, especially since it says "... for manual and schedule builds" when this is a triggered build.

@user26810707,glad to know it works for you. Feel free to let me know if you still have queries on the ticket.
